# Why would /etc/crontab set HOME=/ in environment?

Tags: cron, rpm

I have found that the system crontab `/etc/crontab` in many RedHat (EL/Fedora) based distributions contains the line:

> HOME=/

This config also seems to be shown in many docs/examples across the Internet, and was obviously this way for many years before apparently being removed in the [1.10-34 version of the RPM in 2010](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/crontabs.git/commit/?id=7aff2ac91cecc9d5ac64720fb3894bea9021ba26). *Maybe similar config exists in Debian/other based installs, if readers have definitive knowledge of  distribs with same config please add in comments and I will expand text here.*

The question I'm asking here is:
**What are good technical reasons for setting HOME to the filesystem root in the system crontab?** I am only interested in technical theories, or preferably historical reasons, as to why this config existed for so many years in some distributions, not opinions. I simply want to be aware of what problems I could be causing removing this config in older distribs where it is standard - presumably these reasons no longer exist in upstream versions where it has been removed, or perhaps whoever removed was not aware of the potential problems this fixes.

I recently solved a problem by removing this `HOME=/` on an EL6 system and my research suggested this config has been standard on many systems for many years. It seems to me this would likely cause more problems than it solved, so I became interested in any situations it could have helped with that I could be opening myself up to by removing.

As background the problem was where a cron fired `mysqladmin` command seemed to start ignoring it's `~/.my.cny` - it appears a different MySQL install, or update, started using `$HOME/.my.cnf` as opposed to the `.my.cnf` in the home directory from `/etc/passwd`. I add this just in case anyone else hits a similar problem and can maybe find a speedier resolution with this info.

Comment: Please give reasoning if you feel the need to downvote - and maybe I can improve the Q.

Comment: I'd like to add that I do understand that this question may get no answer for a long time, simply because no-one who has actually has the historical facts (or a good theory) comes across it for a long time - but if it remains closed then when that important person does find this then it will be difficult for them to answer and enlighten us all. So please vote to reopen if you are even interested.

Answer (score 1):

Daemons typically perform a `chdir("/")` or equivalent so they are not started up in some (possibly remote mounted) directory and thus needlessly complicate the un- or re-mounting of said directory. The `HOME=/` of cron jobs likely emulates that, so that random (possibly long-running) jobs are not needlessly in a directory in urgent need of un- or re-mounting. (Granted if `~/.my.cnf` is required and is on a remote mounted directory, then that's a needless fragility in that *when* the network or remote system goes down, that cron job will be unhappy.)

On OpenBSD, the `root` crontab file actually sets things to

```
HOME=/var/log
```

by default. If you want to test what the home directory is because you're not sure where the setting is coming from or is then write a cron job that tells you that (and be sure to remove it before augh the cron spam):

```
* * * * * /bin/pwd
```

Also! Fully qualifying the paths to configuration files can help avoid a wrong configuration file being picked up on due to an environment setting leaking in or from a local file in a local directory.

(On a historical note, the files for `root` used to be in `/` and not `/root` on some flavors of unix and anywhere up to everything could have been mounted in from elsewhere; disks were much more expensive back in the day...)

Comment: I just had to confirm the HOME env set in a crontab would effectively set a cron jobs cwd as I wasn't 100% sure it would, it does for me; so this may indeed have been at least some of the reasoning. Although the system /etc/crontab jobs are run in /root without the line, and this is very unlikely to be on a remote disk, or even a partition that anyone would want to mess with...

Comment: Per your edit: The pwd trick is exactly what I had done to confirm :)
Also, good general advice on fully qualifying in crontab, etc. - and I was aware of older *nix having roots files in /; I've actually used a couple of those _back in the day_ :)